# ASP.NET getting a hidden field's value after a partial postback

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asynchronous, postback

in my ASP.NET page I have an update panel, and in the updatepanel_Load event I have the following code:

```
if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") 
{
   HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField();
   hiddenField.ID ="hiddenField1";
   hiddenField.Value = "0";
   placeHolder1.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
} 
else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" )
{
    HiddenField hiddenField = placeHolder1.FindControl("hiddenField1") as HiddenField;
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenField.Value);
}
```

so basically I'm adding hiddenFields to a placeholder upon, then setting their values with a clientside script, then trying to read the values again on an asynchronous postback in the updatepanel_Load event.

The problem is that FindControl returns null because the placeholder1.Controls.Count is 0 at this point. Why is it zero? I added the hidden field prior to the postback.

Thanks for any help

Comment: upon the initial updatepanel_Load *

Comment: Why are you adding the HiddenField programmatically? I think the problem is that it field is getting created and destroyed in the life cycle and that viewstate will not be holding any value for it. Also, if you are going to add controls in the code behind like that, I would do it in the Init phase to avoid other viewstate issues.

Comment: Did you check if `if` block is executed before `else if`? Just wanted to confirm if `triggeredRefresh` & `triggeredCheck` are properly set.

Comment: Reddy, yes I did check this already, and the first part of the if block is always executed first.. Layoric I am adding the field programmatically as I am actually looping through rows in a database and adding the hiddenfields dynamically based on what is in the database... Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any controls that you add dynamically will disappear upon postbacks. Therefore it does not exist when the page is returned. Like the Layoric said it is being destroyed during the page lifecycle. I would say if you can then just put the hiddenfield inline, as it is a hiddenfield and if you don't need it then just don't look at it (it can still sit there otherwise).

Keep in mind that when an ASP.NET page is "posted back" it goes through the entire page lifecycle. This means that when the page is first loaded it goes through page preinit, init, load, prerender, render, etc. Then when it is posted back it goes through at least preinit, init, and load (there could be other events as well, I can't recall off the top of my head) before any events are fired.

Comment: Ok, well I can't put the hiddenfield inline as I am looping through rows in a database and adding the hiddenfields dynamically based on what is in the database... Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes there is a MUCH better way to do this. Try using an asp.net repeater. Push whatever the values you need to put on the page into something that implements ienumerable and bind it with the repeater. The repeater works by copying everything within it's itemtemplate tags for each item in the bound ienumerable. I would recommend just using the values that you want as "commandargument"s for whatever button is clicked, and then in the event handler that you attach to the button just check what the commandargument of the sender is and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `HttpContext.Request.Form[hiddenField1.UniqueID]`.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't `HttpContext.Request.Form["hiddenField1"]` work?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.. but it changes the key in the Request.Form so it ends up being Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$hiddenField1"]  .. and I don't know how to get the "ctl00$MainContent$"  string from the serverside code so I don't know how I can do it that way :s

Comment: It's going to be in the `ClientID` property.

Comment: @Jimmy, if you defined the `ClientIDMode` as `Static`, it will not generate a different client ID, and this will work.  **[See the Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)**

Comment: but I don't have access to that property.. because I don't have the control in my code at the point when I'm wanting to get the hidden field values.. my initial problem is that FindControl is returning null, and so I can't get the HiddenField control when I am checking the values. if I had access to the control I could just use the Value property anyway

Comment: I already tried that too.. I used hiddenField.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;   but it still posted to the form with the key "ctl00$MainContent$hiddenField1"  .. I think because it uses the 'name' property and not the 'id' property when posting values back?

Comment: @Jimmy, Well, I'm not sure why, but you could still loop through the Form collection and look for any keys that contain the string `hiddenField1`